# how do i get python's mechanize to stop following meta refresh redirects?

Tags: python, redirect, refresh, mechanize, meta-tags

I have a script which gets a webpage with a meta refresh. I need to parse the retrieved page but mechanize seems to follow the redirect. How do I get it to stop following it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply disable it

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_refresh(False)
```